# How to get all filename in a given directory

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I want to get the file name in a given path is there any apis available . My programming environment is vc++ mfc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28VS.85%29.aspx), or MFC's wrapper for them, [CFileFind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) has a great platform independent [filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).  It'll work with MFC.

Here's an example from [their reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_directory_iterator):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using std::tr2::sys;
using std::cout;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string p(argc <= 1 ? "." : argv[1]);

  if (is_directory(p))
  {
    for (directory_iterator itr(p); itr!=directory_iterator(); ++itr)
    {
      cout << itr->path().filename() << ' '; // display filename only
      if (is_regular_file(itr->status())) cout << " [" << file_size(itr->path()) << ']';
      cout << '\n';
    }
  }
  else cout << (exists(p) ? "Found: " : "Not found: ") << p << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use MFC: [CFileFind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is also [CListBox::Dir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hdx240b%28VS.80%29.aspx). It's very convenient if you want to fill a list box with file names.